# IXmlSerializable with valid XmlSchema (XMLSchema:schema' element is not declared..)

Tags: .net, ixmlserializable, xmlschemaset

I am trying to implement IXmlSerializable.
My class implements serializable and writes a single string. I wish to be able to export an object graph schema using XsdDataContractExporter (the standard one).

The class serializes to a simple xml.

```
<Urn ns='http://palantir.co.za/urn'>somestring</Urn>
```

My implementation of GetSchema, which corresponds to the XmlSchemaProvider attribute is as follows.

I need to be able to generate and export the schema.

```
    public static XmlQualifiedName GetSchema(XmlSchemaSet xs)
    {
        string ns = "http://palantir.co.za/urn";
        if (xs.Schemas("http://palantir.co.za/urn").Count != 0)
            return new XmlQualifiedName("Urn", ns); // tried many.

        XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();
        schema.Namespaces.Add("xs", XmlSchema.Namespace);
        schema.Namespaces.Add("Urn", ns); // tried many prefixes.
        schema.ElementFormDefault = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified;
        schema.Items.Add(
            new XmlSchemaElement() {                    
                Name = "Urn",
                SchemaTypeName = XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(XmlTypeCode.String).QualifiedName
            });

        schema.TargetNamespace = ns;
        xs.Add(schema);
        //xs.Compile();
        return new XmlQualifiedName("Urn", schema.TargetNamespace);
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
The http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:schema element is not declared..
```

when I try to export the schema.

Comment: 'Export the schema': you mean when you add it to an XML file for implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Try compose XSD schema in separate file (it much easier that composing in runtime).
Make sure it's correnct.
Place xsd schema into your assembly as a resource.
Then, in your GetSchema method just deserialize it :

```
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    return XmlSchema.Read(stream, null);
}
```

Also notice that your method GetSchema will be called in runtime on any (de)serialization.
So desirializing schema each time itsn't good idea.